# How do I add data from a string field to the model as a property?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dapper, unit-of-work

I am separating a string field I have below by splitting it.

String : D837D323-40A0-1EDD-F365-A55C43725DE0|SPECODE,10A4F529-CDFB-7553-0D05-7C9A36A721F8|SPECODE2,BCAA7E77-DF1D-3135-AD4C-823CEC02ED56|SPECODE3,24CC7FBE-5F43-67FC-7998-73869E2B6D5B|SPECODE4,DF15B062-3072-E3A3-A268-F2DEC8CF947B|SPECODE5,F56355C9-CCF6-095E-F697-DE36BAF464A7|CYPHCODE

Split & UnitOfWork :

```cs
using (var dbFactory = new DbFactory()){

    var specialCodeList = new List<SpecialCodeModel>();
    string[] specialCode = _settings.SpecialCode.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < specialCode.Length; i++)
    {
        int position = specialCode[i].IndexOf('|');
        specialCodeList.Add(new SpecialCodeModel
        {
            EkGuid = specialCode[i].Substring(0, position),
            ErpProperty = specialCode[i].Substring(position + 1),
            SystemTypeName = "System.String"
        });
    }

    var factory = new DynamicTypeFactory();
    var extendedType = factory.CreateNewTypeWithDynamicProperties(typeof(CustomerDto),
        specialCodeList);

    // Get all read/write properties for the extended Type.
    var properties = extendedType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                 .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite);



    var connection = dbFactory.GetConnection(_settings);
    _settings = GetLogoFirmInfo(parameters, _settings, connection);

    string query = SetLogoDbSettings(LogoSqlCommands.CustomerListCountCmd(), parameters, _settings);
    int dataCount = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<int>(query);

    query = SetLogoDbSettings(LogoSqlCommands.CustomerListCmd(_settings), parameters, _settings);
    var data = connection.Query<CustomerDto>(query);

    return QueryResult<IEnumerable<CustomerDto>>.CreateResult(data, dataCount, parameters.PagingLimit, parameters.PagingOffset);
}
```

Then I assign SpecialCodeModel to this model.
What I want to do is to automatically add the EkGuid fields to the CustomerDto model as a System.String property. Then I add a query using dapper with ErpProperty.The query formed as EKGuid AS ErpProperty should bring me a full CustomerDto.Of course, with the fields, I added specifically.
I tried something, it added to the model, but the dapper did not fill the fields :( I need help with this.

Comment: C# is statically typed - which means you cannot mutate types at runtime, such as adding properties to types - which I think is what you're asking?

Comment: @Dai no. I want add new property automatically. Which property example :
public string D837D323-40A0-1EDD-F365-A55C43725DE0 {get; set;} and others...

Comment: What do you mean by "add a new property automatically"? That sounds like you want to mutate a type, which as I've explained, is impossible in a statically typed language like C#.

Comment: Use a [Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0) to store key value pairs. For me it looks like `SPECODE` should be the property name and `" D837D323-40A0-1EDD-F365-A55C43725DE0"` the value.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks for the answer. I thought of that too. But will I be able to add the data that comes with dapper to customerDto? These fields can come dynamically with a different IDGuid each time.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes My key is a column name in the IDGUID SPECODE database.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: Construct a SQL command by using a fixed set of aliases that can be mapped by Dapper:

```sql
SELECT
    [D837D323-40A0-1EDD-F365-A55C43725DE0] AS Column1,
    [10A4F529-CDFB-7553-0D05-7C9A36A721F8] AS Column2
    ...
FROM mytable
```

Now, you can create a class having a fixed set of properties

```
public class Data
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The SQL command can be constructed like this:

```cs
var specialCodes = _settings.SpecialCode.Split(',')
    .Select(s => {
        string[] parts = s.Split('|');
        return new SpecialCodeModel {
            EkGuid = parts[0],
            ErpProperty = parts[1],
            SystemTypeName = "System.String"
        };
    });


var selectList = specialCodes
    .Select((s, i) => $"[{s.EkGuid}] AS Column{i + 1}");

string sql = $"SELECT\r\n  {String.Join(",\r\n  ", selectList)}\r\nFROM myTable";

Console.WriteLine(sql);
```

With the string from above it creates this output:

```
SELECT
  [D837D323-40A0-1EDD-F365-A55C43725DE0] AS Column1,
  [10A4F529-CDFB-7553-0D05-7C9A36A721F8] AS Column2,
  [BCAA7E77-DF1D-3135-AD4C-823CEC02ED56] AS Column3,
  [24CC7FBE-5F43-67FC-7998-73869E2B6D5B] AS Column4,
  [DF15B062-3072-E3A3-A268-F2DEC8CF947B] AS Column5,
  [F56355C9-CCF6-095E-F697-DE36BAF464A7] AS Column6
FROM myTable
```

Make sure to escape the column names the appropriate way for the DB type (`[]` for SQL-Server, `""` for Oracle, etc.).

Comment: But these names are not in the db :( column1 column2 etc I need names in string SPECODE etc.

I need this;
  [D837D323-40A0-1EDD-F365-A55C43725DE0] AS SPECODE,

Comment: Well, then use `var selectList = specialCodes.Select((s, i) => $"[{s.EkGuid}] AS {s.ErpProperty }");`. But i am not sure what you mean by "these names are not in the db". The SELECT command is there to retrieve data. column named `[D837D323-40A0-1EDD-F365-A55C43725DE0]` must be in the db. The alias after the `AS` does not need to be in the DB; however, it must be in the class. This is the property Dapper want to map.